# Django, legacy PostgreSQL database, multiple primary keys

Tags: django, database, postgresql, primary-key, legacy

I suppose that question as old as it possibly could be, but I still have a hope that maybe someone has found some magical solution.

Everything is simple, I have a database (postgresql) with small table as an example, with already existing field with Primary key:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sdUd.png)

My goal is to add an ID field as a second primary key.
My Model looks like this:

```
class CdcConn(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    conn_type = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    conn_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'cdc_conn'
```

After migration the result output is:

> `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple primary keys for table "cdc_conn" are not allowed`

Tried many options, unique_together, constraints, some additional modules such as django-viewflow, and so on.
The issue is about 15 years old, documentation says that composite pk are not allowed, but still, I can't believe that such powerful tool as Django just can't handle that simple operation.

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add a UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: Did you mean something like this?
UniqueConstraint(fields = ['id',], name = 'new_constraint')